# Delete / Clear all events that created by Google Calendar API

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have an application using Google Calendar API.

```
 private function getClient() {
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->setScopes('primary');
    return $client;
}
```

Credential is a service_account.
I created and inserted about 65000 events by the above client.
Now, I want to deleted all events (65000 events).
I want to use /clear (
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/clear)  API to do that but I am not sure it will delete all events from my application without clear other events on my calendar.
I mean on my calendar there are 2 type of events:

1. Personal Event, created by Rakumo calendar
2. Event from my application.

I just want to delete all events created from 2.

Anybody can confirm when use /clear API

```
$service->calendars->clear('primary');
```

will it delete only all events created from my application ?

Comment: are they two separate calendars or are all events written in one calendar?

Comment: @noogui : they are all events in one calendar.

Comment: it says in the docs that clear deletes all events from a calendar. That sounds pretty clear to me.

Comment: I find out that if the service is using the Google Account service and the calendar id is primary, you can not use the clear api to clear all event of the 'primary' calendar.

Comment: @noogui: The answer is, we can not use clear method with calendar id is 'primary' with Google Account Service.